# How to add ENUM in Spring-app and PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, enums

There is a class `User` I linked, `Administrator`, `Customer`, `Cook`. Accordingly, he created the `ENUM` class with the enumerations *COOK*, *ADMIN*, *CUSTOMER*. `PostgreSQL` also created a `user_role` of type `enum`. Then I don’t understand what I’m doing wrong. I use `Spring MVC`. `AdminRepo` has created a method that searches for users by `role`. A method has been created in `AdminController` that returns everything by choice by `role`. Throws an error during execution!

User:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Set;

@ApiModel
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class User {

    public User() { // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public User(String name, String lastName, String role,
                String login, String password) { // Базовый конструктор

        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.role = role;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }


    // Поля
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Size(min = 5)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "rolik")
    private Role roles;



    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Admin:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@ApiModel
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class Admin {

    public Admin() { // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    // Поля

    // name, lastName, login, password берем от класса User через связи;

    @ApiModelProperty
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;


    // Relationships
    //
    @ApiModelProperty
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id") // Join without Admin in User class
    private User user;
}
```

AdminController:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.controller;

import com.tinychiefdelights.model.*;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.AdminRepository;
import com.tinychiefdelights.service.AdminService;
import com.tinychiefdelights.service.UserService;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;


@Api(value = "Работа с Админом", tags = {"Администратор"})
@RestController
public class AdminController {

    // Constructor
    //
    // Inject через конструктор
    @Autowired
    public AdminController(AdminRepository adminRepository, AdminService adminService, UserService userService) {
        this.adminRepository = adminRepository;
        this.adminService = adminService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    // Поля
    // All injects into constructor
    private final AdminRepository adminRepository;

    private final AdminService adminService;

    private final UserService userService;


    // Методы
    //



    // Вывод информации по конкретному заказу по ID
    @GetMapping("admin/getalladminis/")
    Admin getAllAdminis() {
        return adminRepository.findByUserRoles(Role.ADMIN);
    }
```

AdminRepo:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.repository;

import com.tinychiefdelights.model.Admin;
import com.tinychiefdelights.model.Role;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface AdminRepository extends JpaRepository<Admin, Long> { // Интерфейс для репозитория Admin


    Admin findByUserRoles(Role role);
}
```

[image]

[image]

```java
2020-04-28 21:59:42.859 ERROR 1352 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: operator does not exist: user_role = character varying
  Hint: An operator with the given name and argument types was not found. Perhaps you should add explicit type conversions.

  Position: 137
2020-04-28 21:59:42.929 ERROR 1352 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: statement does not exist: user_role = character varying
  Hint: An operator with the given name and argument types was not found. Perhaps you should add explicit type conversions.
  Position: 137
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2578) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2313) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:331) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.2.11.jar:42.2.11]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1562) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1578) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.findByUserRoles(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.tinychiefdelights.controller.AdminController.getAllAdminis(AdminController.java:46) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Which one is the problematic column?

Comment: ROLIK column in pg_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of column `rolik` in the database making it an actual string (`varchar`), right now you have defined it as of `user_role` type.

The statements:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "rolik")
private Role roles;
```

specify that the enum will be serialized as string in the database.

Comment: new exc 'javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2'

Comment: OK, now the mapping is working. You have a problem in your query: you expect unique result but more are returned.

Comment: thansk's Man! Okey